# [__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have EAGLView hodling presentFrameBuffer and saving the screenshot from EAGLView send this sreenshot to UIViewController for UIActivityViewController social network framework. So, i saved in `NSUserDefaults` then retrieve in UIViewController. But i'm getting Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: `'*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'`

EAGLView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage * screensht;

   @property (nonatomic, copy) UIButton * save;
```

EAGLview.mm

```
- (BOOL)presentFramebuffer
 {


 if (_takePhotoFlag)

 {


 UIImage *glImage = [self glToUIImage];
 self.screensht = [self createSavableImage:glImage];

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.screensht) forKey:@"image"];

 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.screensht, nil, nil, nil);

 }

 glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

 return [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
 }

 -(void)save:(id)sender{


 _takePhotoFlag = YES;

 }
```

Viewcontroller.mm:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 [eaglView.save addTarget:self action:@selector(save:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 }



 -(void)save:(id)sender{


 NSLog(@"save click");

 NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"];
 UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];



 NSArray *activityItems = @[image];

 UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
 avc.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, nil];
 [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];



 }
```

NSUserDefaults Null:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.screensht) forKey:@"image"];

         NSLog(@"nsuserdefauls is %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"image"]);

nsuserdefauls is (null)
```

Comment: Seems like the retrieved image is nil? Did you check it?

Comment: Do you save the image successfully?

Comment: yes i can save the image in photo album using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.screensht, nil, nil, nil);

Comment: Are you getting the image back from NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I'm sure that the `image` is nil.

Comment: @MidhunMP: The image is storing to photo album.

Comment: The image is storing to photo album but the NSUserDefaults getting null value.

Comment: Your problem with your image is that you are calling `stringForKey`, not `objectForKey`, which will return the NSData that represents your image.

Comment: @Paulw11: where should i change my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your image as an NSData object, but trying to retrieve it using `stringForKey` - this will give you nil because the "image" key does not contain a string.  You should use

```
NSData *imageData=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"]);
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the answer was that I was calling

```
if([_something respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)])
{
   id a = [_something objectForKey:@"someKey"];
}
```

but '_something' was 'nil' and that's where I was getting the crash

Comment: sending a message to nil is ok in objective c. The thing that you was senting objectForKey probably was not KVO compliant